# Is there a better way to write the full contents of a file to an OutputStream?

Tags: java, io

When I want to write the full contents of a file into an `OutputStream`, I usually allocate a buffer as a `byte[]`, then make a `for` loop to `read` data from the file's `InputStream` into the buffer and write the buffer contents into the `OutputStream`, until the `InputStream` has no more bytes available.

This seems rather clumsy to me. Is there a better way to do this?

Also, I am always unsure about the buffer size. Usually, I am allocating 1024 bytes, because it just feels good. Is there a better way to determine a reasonable buffer size?

In my current case, I want to copy the full contents of a file into the output stream that writes the contents of an HTTP response. So, this is not a question about how to copy files on the file system.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For Java 1.7+ you can use the [Files.copy(Path, OutputStream)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.io.OutputStream)), e.g.

```
HttpServletResponse response = // ...
File toBeCopied = // ...

try (OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream()) {
    Path path = toBeCopied.toPath();
    Files.copy(path, out);
    out.flush();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Note, since you are dealing with `HttpServletResponse` is is also a good idea to set correct response headers. Add the following lines *before* you copy the actual file data to the response:

```
String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(toBeCopied.getName());
String contentDisposition = String.format("attachment; filename=%s", toBeCopied.getName());
int fileSize = Long.valueOf(toBeCopied.length()).intValue();

response.setContentType(mimeType);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisposition);
response.setContentLength(fileSize);
```

Note, the encoding of the file name passed to the content disposition is important, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http).

Comment: How could my unit test verify what's being written to the OutputStream? ServletOutputStream mockOutput = mock(ServletOutputStream.class);
  when(response.getOutputStream()).thenReturn(mockOutput);

Answer (score 30):

Apache Commons-IO:

```
IOUtils.copy(fileInputStream,outputStream);
```

JDK NIO

```
new FileInputStream(file).getChannel().transferTo(otherChannel);
```

Comment: Wow. I gave a short comment regarding Commons-IO at Bozho's answer. But the channel solution is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot, all of NIO channels passed me by, because I had already learned Java IO before NIO existed.

And, by the way: 9 minutes! That's almost as fast as lightning.

Comment: don't forget to close the `FileInputStream`

Answer (score 12):

With [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) you have a one-line solution:

```
IOUtils.copy(yourFileInputStream, outputStream);
```

Note that you'd have to close your streams manually (or by `IOUtils.closeQuitely(..)`)

Comment: This would be my suggestion as well. Though what it does is the same thing.

Comment: That looks really nice. But for this simple task, it seems a little overdone to me to include another library. Of course, if there are more reasons to include Commons-IO, then this will be the solution of choice.