# How to serve static HTML file in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have an EchoServer that I was provided to run and serve static local HTML files on my computer. It would then put out an error if the files were non-existent. I want to know how do I provide a local file path in this code?

I'm practically new to the language and do not really know how it works.

This is my main class in which I try to run the server.

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val server = new ServerSocket(9999)
    while(true) {
      try {
        serve(server)
        //Maybe the filepath goes here?
      }catch {
        case e: Exception => ("File not found")
      }

    }
  }
```

While these two is what takes in the input

```
object EchoServer {
  def read_and_write(in: BufferedReader, out:BufferedWriter): Unit = {
    out.write(in.readLine())
    out.flush()
    in.close()
    out.close()
  }

  def serve(server: ServerSocket): Unit = {
      val s = server.accept()
      val in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream))
      val out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream))

      read_and_write(in, out)

      s.close()
  }
```

So if I get it to run properly it would read any existing HTML file, and if not output an error if it does not exist on my local machine.

Comment: You could open a FileInputStream to your file and copy that into the `out` from the socket stream. But isn't this way too low-level? Wouldn't you want to at least use the HTTP protocol ?

Comment: How would I do that exactly? Sorry still new to this.

Comment: You can use `Files.copy`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741419/is-there-a-better-way-to-write-the-full-contents-of-a-file-to-an-outputstream

Answer (score 1):

Echo server is relatively simple because it operates on ECHO Protocol[1]. If you need to serve static files, unless you want to implement your own protocol over TCP/UDP I would recommend you use any of the available web frameworks in Scala to do that over HTTP(s).

There are lot of [web frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488412/what-scala-web-frameworks-are-available) in Scala and most of them should support serving a folder or a static file right out of the web server.

A simple example using Scalatra would be to put the files you want to serve in the `webapp` folder and be done with it. You can read more about it [here](http://scalatra.org/getting-started/project-structure.html). If you want to perform any kind of validation on the input request you can also write a small API that do those validations post which can serve the files over the wire.

[1] - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc862